# Macros of Item Key in Zabbix

Tags: macros, key, zabbix

I am new to Zabbix, I have a question how the Macros works in the Item Key

Entry in `zabbix_agentd.win.conf`:

```
UserParameter=datt[*],echo $1
```

**The hosts items:**
[image]

**The latest data:**
[image]

Why the Macros of HOST.HOST shows correct while TIME and DATE wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the Zabbix manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location), `{HOST.HOST}` is supported in many locations, including `Item key parameters`. Both `{DATE}` and `{TIME}` are only supported in the following locations - notice item key parameters missing there:

- Trigger-based notifications and commands
- Discovery notifications
- Auto-registration notifications
- Internal notifications